# How to highlight code in hbs template?

Tags: ember.js

I want to introduce into my project some code to be highlighted on certain pages (like index.hbs) I've searched for libraries that can do this and found tools like highlight.js, but I was unable to use it in my ember project. Can anyone explain how to import a custom library like highlight.js or can someone give me a recomandation for a tool. I've tried to use this tool: [ember-cli-eg-code-highlight](https://github.com/EmberGrep/ember-cli-eg-code-highlight), but it is not specified how to use it. Ok I have installed it, pasted the `{{highlight-js code=file lang=language hasLineNumbers=hasLineNumbers}}` in my index.hbs, but it does not work. Also the `ENV.emberHighlightJs: { style: 'arta' }`;I have no ideea where to put it. Tried to put it inember-cli-build.js but it is not working.

I have found also [markdown-code-highlighting](https://tonicdev.com/npm/markdown-code-highlighting). But I am lost at this step: "In your Brocfile you'll need to import the CSS styling you want for the highlighter. " So where exactly is my brocfile in my ember project?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/ef4/ember-code-snippet they seem to have easy to follow instructions and it uses highlight.js for the actual highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

Did you restart `ember server` ?

You can find example of using  ember-cli-eg-code-highlight here: https://github.com/EmberGrep/ember-cli-eg-code-highlight/blob/master/tests/dummy/app/templates/application.hbs

But it looks like addon is buggy. So it worth to check this PR https://github.com/EmberGrep/ember-cli-eg-code-highlight/pull/9

P.S. about brocfile -- now it names as `ember-cli-build.js` at the root of project

Comment: Yeah I've tried to restart ember server, but did not worked.

Comment: I check highlight.js -- it will be easy to create your own component. What is your goal?

Comment: My goal is to be able to put code in my page and render it as in a code editor. (What hightlight.js is doing.)

Comment: @Cristian well, hightlight display code in readonly mode. If you need editor - check 'ember-cli-ace' addon

Comment: sorry for not being able to be more precise. So basicly I am building a blog in which I want to explain to people some code. So the blog page must contain the code that I am writing about. The code in the page must not be editable (like in a file editor, like ace for example), but it must be highlighted as code. So I don't want all the code to be black, or white, but functions to be a color, conditions other color, variables other color etc... So this is what I want to achieve using some library that does this. Thank you for your response until now.